# syntax error while trying to dynamically change imgs using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the main photo on my webpage to one that is highlighted on mouseover. The code below results in a bug saying that there is something wrong with my quotation marks. What could be the problem here?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".colorDiv").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("border", "2px solid #2F4F4F");
        $(".mPhoto['src="photos/WP_20140621_002.jpg"']").attr("src", ".colorImg");
    });
    $(".colorDiv").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css("border", "none");
    })
});
```

`.colorImg` is the class of the imgs that I want to change original image with

`.mPhoto` is class of main photo that I want to change

Answer (score 1):

In such selectors you don't need quotes.
The correct variant is:

```
$(".mPhoto[src=photos/WP_20140621_002.jpg]").attr("src", ".colorImg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem are the quotes. 
If I understood but you are trying to do, this is :

```
$(".mPhoto").attr("src", "photos/WP_20140621_002.jpg");
```

Comment: I think what u said fixed it but the images still aren't changing, instead I'm getting a change but only the alternate display text.

Comment: @user3879560 check that I wrote `NEW_IMG_SRC_HERE`. You must put there the new src to be changed.

Comment: @user3879560 Check my edit now, I think that now I understood but you are trying to say.